# Method that returns a string from a given double

Tags: string, methods, type-conversion

I'm stuck on this one exercise where I'm supposed to write a method called setGrade(double points) which after being given a floating point number between 0-50 returns a string with the letter, F,E,D,C,B,A. The limits should be: 25 = E, 30 = D, 35 = C, 40 = B, 45 = A

I could complete this task quite easily with just if's after creating a double for every limit and then just use if-loops. But I'm confused on how to solve it when I should return a string.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Like I said, I was able to complete the task by creating an int for every one of the values, and then use if loops to compare and print out the result. But I'm supposed to return a string with letter, which has to be changed fom the floating point number. And that is what I dont know how to do.